# Compression/encryption algorithms output guarantees

Tags: algorithm, encryption, compression, implementation

My question here regards compression/encryption algorithms in general and to me sounds like a complete noobie one. Now, I understand that "in general" "it all depends", but suppose we're talking algorithms that all have reference implementation/published specs and are overall ever so standard. To be more specific, I'm using .NET implementations of AES-256 and GZip/Deflate

So here goes. Can it be assumed that, given *exactly* the same input, both types of algorithms will produce *exactly* the same output.

For example, will output of `aes(gzip("hello"), key, initVector))` on .NET be identical to that of on a Mac or Linux?

Comment: Yes, if the implementation (algorithm) is _exactly the same_. If it's strictly standard-compliant AES-256 - it will indeed be the same.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Are compression algorithms the same?

Comment: Side note: gzipping (compressing) AES or otherwise encrypted output does not sound very convincing. If the encryption algorithm is good, it should output something "very random", thus having a high entropy, thus compression will be quite inefficient. You should rather `aes(gzip("hello"),key,initVector)`

Comment: @zerm Whoops, that's my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton Gogolev: gzip is a flexible format with many settings, but it is determinate as well.

Comment: And about compression -- I'm not sure whether you can guarantee identical output: E.g. I could imagine that for equally likely symbols, Huffman-Encoding has no fixed order? Maybe this is specified in the gzip/zip specs, though. So, i would suggest that it's pretty likely the outputs are identical, but i assume you can compress something into a different output which still conforms to the standard.

Comment: The output of AES will be the same if and only if the input, initial vector, and key are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AES is rigourosly defined, so given same input, same algorithm, and same key, you will get the same output.

It cannot be said the same for zip.

The problem is not the standard. There IS a defined standard : Deflate stream is [IETF RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950), gzip stream is [IETF RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952), so anyone can produce a compatible zip compressor/decoder starting from these definitions.

But zip belong to the large family of LZ compressors, which, by construction, are neither bijective nor injective. Which means, from a single source, there are many many ways to describe the same input which are all valid although different.

An example.
Let's say, my input is : ABCABCABC

Valid outputs can be :

- 9 literals
- 3 literals followed by one copy of 6 bytes long starting at offset -3
- 3 literals followed by two copies of 3 bytes long each starting at offset -3
- 6 literals followed by one copy of 3 bytes long starting at offset -6
- etc.

All these outputs are valid and describe (regenerate) the same input. Obviously, one of them is more efficient (compress more) than the others. But that's where implementation may differ. Some will be more powerful than others. For example, it is known that [kzip](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm) and [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) generate better (more compressed) zip files than gzip. Even gzip has a lot of compression options generating different compressed streams starting from a same input.

Now, if you want to constantly get exactly the same binary output, you need more than "zip" : you need to enforce a *precise* zip implementation, and a precise compression parameter. Then, you'll be sure that you generate always the same binary.

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Thanks a lot! One more thing, though. Can I be sure that one particular zip implementation will always produce the same output for the same input?

Comment: In theory yes, at least if the implementation is "correctly" coded. It can sometimes happen that an implementation produce different result depending on the CPU they run on, due to FPU rounding error, little/big endian, random init, etc. But this is considered a flaw, so no "good" implementation should behave like that.

Comment: If your zip implementation uses floating point computation, I think it needs a serious talking to.

Answer (score 2):

AES is defined to a standard, so any conforming implementation will indeed produce the same output.  GZip is a program, so it is possible that different versions of the program will produce different outputs.  I would expect a later version to be able to reinflate the output from an earlier version, but the reverse may not be possible.

As others have said, if you are going to compress, then compress the plaintext, not the cyphertext from AES.  Cyphertext won't compress well as it is designed to appear random.

Comment: Thanks! Now, is there any _compression_ algorithm defined to a standard that you might know of?